# PSQL timestamp syntax

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a go function that inserts data into a table with a statement prepared and executed similar to the following:

```
func Insert(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    db := dbConn()
    if r.Method == "POST" {
        email := r.FormValue("email")
        firstName := r.FormValue("firstName")
        lastName := r.FormValue("lastName")
        createdOn := time.Now().UTC()

        insForm, err := db.Prepare(`INSERT INTO public.users(email, firstName, lastName, created_on) VALUES ($1,$2, $3, $4)`)
        CheckError(err)
        insForm.Exec(email, firstName, lastName, createdOn)

    defer db.Close()

    http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 301)
}
```

The psql error returned is:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "2022-08-04 17:45:40.10189 +0000 UTC"
LINE 1: ...) VALUES ('test3@testing.com', 'test', 'testing', '2022-08-0...`
```

dbConn is defined as:

```
   func dbConn() (db *sql.DB) {
    // pass the db credentials into variables
    host := goDotEnvVariable("DBHOST")
    port := goDotEnvVariable("DBPORT")
    dbUser := goDotEnvVariable("DBUSER")
    dbPass := goDotEnvVariable("DBPASS")
    dbname := goDotEnvVariable("DBNAME")
    // create a connection string
    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s "+
        "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        host, port, dbUser, dbPass, dbname)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return db
}
```

What is the correct syntax to enter the timestamp with the appropriate UTC time zone?

Comment: "for type timestamp", that is different from "timestamp with the appropriate UTC time zone". What datatype do you use for created_on? (by the way, in PostgreSQL 14 your input is accepted for both data types)

Comment: That is valid syntax: `select '2022-08-04 17:45:40.10189 +0000'::timestamp;  08/04/2022 17:45:40.10189`. Where are you seeing the error?

Comment: @FrankHeikens created_on is type time.Time

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I'm logging out the values passed to the DB when submitting the form on the page. It redirects as intended but nothing is added to the DB. I get the error when I manually run the query in a PSQL shell using the values previously logged.

Comment: `2022-08-04 17:45:40.10189 +0000 UTC` says the time zone twice. Once as an offset, `+0000`, and once as a name, `UTC`. The correct format has one or the other. [Here is a demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=418d718a0a83f462aa396e558b637956). However, [libpq](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq) should have converted the `Time` value correctly for you. Are you using libpq? Can we see `dbConn`?

Comment: Now I see the error, you both use +0000 for the time zone offset but also UTC. Use just one

Comment: What is your type for `created_at` in database schema?

Comment: @Schwern I've updated the post to include dbCOnn and yes, I am using libpq

Comment: @FrankHeikens if I remove the UTC call on time.now() it defaults to EDT which still returns the invalid syntax error

Comment: @HamzaAnis time.TIme

Comment: @eomolo Is there any reason that led you to generate the value of that column in the application instead of in the database? For fields such as `created_at` I like to let the database handle its generation. `
CREATE TABLE users ( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);
`

Comment: the column created_at is type TIME and you are passing DATE and TIME to the database. The database type TIME is for hour, minute and second only. You need to change the created_at type to TIMESTAMP or TIMESTAMPTZ.

Comment: @PauloPereira No, the type is `timestamp`. It's in the error message: `invalid input syntax for type timestamp` and it [is indeed invalid timestamp syntax](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=418d718a0a83f462aa396e558b637956). The Go type is `time.Time`.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. [Here's the code I ran](https://gist.github.com/schwern/5393b1c4a4aac17ce1a62bbda8a44d8e). PostgreSQL v14.4, lib/pq v1.10.6, Go 1.19. Here is [the relevant part of libpq](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/006a3f492338e7f74b87a2c16d2c4be10cc04ae6/encode.go#L51). What versions are you using?

Comment: @Schwern thanks for putting somuch effort into this. I've updated this post with a fix. It was an oversite on my part when creating this database.

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp formatting was a red herring. It was an oversite not to implement a panic after the SQL statement execution and after doing so, I was able to capture a permissions error.

```
        insForm, err := db.Prepare(`INSERT INTO public.users(email, firstName, lastName, created_on) VALUES ($1,$2, $3, $4)`)
        CheckError(err)
        _, err = insForm.Exec(email, firstName, lastName, createdOn)
        CheckError(err)
```

The problem was that while I had created a separate DB user for the application, I had not granted it privileges.

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE <db> TO <user>;`

The invalid input syntax was a result of copying the log output as text directly into a statement instead of converting the time logged into timestampz datatype.